# JPA query ordering by nested property when it is null

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to sort my news by `category.sortOrder`, but sometimes category is null so those values are filtered out. I found that:

```
 ORDER BY news.categoryCountry nulls first
```

Will do the trick for not filtering out the results, but they are still not sorted by `categoryCountry.sortorder`

I have tried this:

```
ORDER BY news.categoryCountry nulls first, news.categoryCountry.sortOrder nulls first
```

Or

```
ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN (news.categoryCountry is NULL) 
THEN news.categoryCountry 
ELSE news.categoryCountry.sortOrder 
END
nulls first
```

Still does not work. Always filtering null values out

Answer (score 0):

if it is not working then you need one expression and one column as follows:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN news.categoryCountry is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 end, 
         news.categoryCountry.sortOrder nulls first
```

Comment: Still does not work. It is filtering out the results with `null` values for `categoryCountry` :(

Comment: Order by do not filter records.